# show products of a category on home page in magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: products, home, list.phtml

i'm getting crazy right now. I'm setting up a template and this easy thing which was done in 5 minutes took my last 3 hours.

I can't figure out why this simple block thing for showing a category on home page is not working anymore in magento 1.9.2.2:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" category_id="7" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

I found out that you have to whitelist that block... how to do this?!

Could anyone help me? I would really appreciate that!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due SUPEE-6788 patten,you can use below:

***As  alternative solution***.

---

goto Design tab of Your cms page

Put below `layout xml  code` at *`Layout Update XML field`*

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" category_id="7" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" />
</reference>
```

**It  will not create issue in permission**

Answer (score 7):

After last patch, SUPEE-6788, Magento includes a white list of allowed blocks or directives. If a module or extension uses variables like `{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}` and `{{block type="catalog/product_list"}}` in CMS pages or emails, and the directives are not on this list, you will need to add them with your database installation script.

You can configure allowed variables and blocks in `System > Permissions > Blocks` and `System > Permissions > Variables`.

SUPEE-6788 complete details: http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details