# magento 1.9.2.2 Display multiple categories on one cms page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, ce-1.9.2.2

Im trying to display multiple categories on one cms page

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" category_id="7" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" />
</reference>
```

from [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90354/show-products-of-a-category-on-home-page-in-magento-1-9-2-2/109656#answer-90363)

it works fine.. but when I tried to display multiple categories, e.g(category='7', category='8'......) in one cms page, its display only one category repeatedly.

how can I make it using this way?

please help.

Comment: Post your code with category='7', category='8'......

Comment: I did this <block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" category_id="7" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" /> <block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" category_id="8" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" />

Comment: What happens if you change the name of the block for every new block ? E.g. `home.catalog.product.list.first`, `home.catalog.product.list.second` etc...

Comment: I got the same result..

Answer (score 0):

I got it using this.

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="home" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
 </block>
<action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name><count>5</count></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

just repeat the block  and change the category_id to what you have and add something on name="home" to name="home.first" every time you add category.

> I think this is a wrong way to achieve this, so i will try to get
>   deeper on magento environment.